# Why echarts4r produces an empty plot when the data contain spaces?

Tags: r, data-visualization, parallel-coordinates, echarts4r

## The context

Let's suppose we have the following two files

File: 1.csv

```
labels,quantity
foo1,1
foo2,4
foo3,6
```

File: 2.csv

```
labels,quantity
foo with spaces 1,1
foo with spaces 2,4
foo with spaces 3,6
```

and we want to create a parallel coordinates plot for each of those two data sets.

The following code loads the data from `1.csv` into `df1` and plot it.

```
library('echarts4r')

df1 <- read.csv('1.csv')

df1 |>
  e_charts()  |>
  e_parallel(labels, quantity)
```

[image]

The following code loads the data from `2.csv` into `df2` and plot it.

```
library('echarts4r')

df2 <- read.csv('2.csv')

df2 |>
  e_charts()  |>
  e_parallel(labels, quantity)
```

[image]

## The problem

As you can see above, `df2` doesn't show the lines as occurs when plotting `df1`.  I suppose this happens because of the spaces found in `2.csv`, so why does this behavior occur when my data contain spaces?

## Additional information

I executed both `str` and `summary` in both data sets to find the reason why this occur, but the information was the same.

```
summary(df1)
summary(df2)
```

```
    labels             quantity    
 Length:3           Min.   :1.000  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:2.500  
 Mode  :character   Median :4.000  
                    Mean   :3.667  
                    3rd Qu.:5.000  
                    Max.   :6.000
    labels             quantity    
 Length:3           Min.   :1.000  
 Class :character   1st Qu.:2.500  
 Mode  :character   Median :4.000  
                    Mean   :3.667  
                    3rd Qu.:5.000  
                    Max.   :6.000
```

```
str(df1)
str(df2)
```

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ labels  : chr  "foo1" "foo2" "foo3"
 $ quantity: int  1 4 6
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ labels  : chr  "foo 1" "foo 2" "foo 3"
 $ quantity: int  1 4 6
```

Comment: I don't know when it changed, but this is no longer an issue. Have has many spaces as you'd like now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right, this happens because of the whitespace in the labels. You can easily remove or replace (by "_") the whitespace using `gsub` like this:

```r
df2 <- read.table(text = "labels,quantity
foo with spaces 1,1
foo with spaces 2,4
foo with spaces 3,6", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

df2$labels <- gsub(" ", "_", df2$labels, fixed = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
df2 |>
  e_charts()  |>
  e_parallel(labels, quantity)
```

[image: ![](https://i.imgur.com/cVuyYXa.png)]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Do yo know how to restart and stop the animation?

Comment: @TarJae, I think [e_animation](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/reference/e_animation.html) could be useful for that.